# Google Sheets Copy Source to Target and Append Todays Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy data from my source sheet

[SourceSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY3Tt.png)

to my target sheet

[TargetSheet with Today's Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOkz.png)

For each new row that I add to the target, I want to add today's date in the "Date" column. I have spent a week trying to solve this with no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code below, how do I add the new Date function?

```
function copyRangeValuesAPPEND() {
let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Source');

let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:D6");
let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Target');
let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,rowCount,columnCount);
targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
```

Comment: Try looking at the Array.splice() method or if you want to put at the beginning you can use unShift() and actually you can put it pretty much anywhere you want with map.  Spend some time learn the array methods they are well worth the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,rowCount,columnCount);
targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
```

#### To:

```
let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rowCount, columnCount + 1);
var date = new Date();
targetRange.setValues(sourceValues.map(e => [...e, date]));
```

- By this modification, `date` is put to the last column to each row.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)